# Как проксировать WebSocket протокол?

Tags: http, websocket, proxy

Как работа происходит по умолчанию.

На хосте есть браузер который управляется pupeteer через API
Мое приложение отправляет запрос на http://localhost:3001/v1.0/browser_profiles/PROFILE_ID/start?automation=1 после чего открывается окно браузера и в ответ приходит порт и ссылка для подключения.

После чего puppeteer подключается по этой ссылке уже по ws:// и начинает управление браузером, вторая ссылка выглядит так.
ws://127.0.0.1:6475/devtools/browser/c71c1a9d-f07c-4dd9-84a9-53a4c6df9969
С каждым таким запросом по первой ссылке приходит новый порт и новая ссылка, если открыто несколько окон, это будет несколько ссылок со своими портами например:

ws://127.0.0.1:6475/devtools/browser/c71c1a9d-f07c-4dd9-84a9-53a4c6df9969
ws://127.0.0.1:6402/devtools/browser/c51c8a0d-f02c-4da9-82a9-17a4c6df0154

Вопрос:
У меня есть хост (A) на котором исходный код моего приложения, а также хосты (BCD...Windows) на которых открыт браузер описанный выше.
Необходимо проксировать эти connection.

Что я предпринял:

Было запущено ngrok соединение по TCP на хосте (B) он выдал ссылку с доменом и своим портом.
Ссылка для подключения pupeteer на хосте (A) уже выглядела не так

ws://127.0.0.1:6475/devtools/browser/c71c1a9d-f07c-4dd9-84a9-53a4c6df9969

А вот так:

ws://4.tcp.ngrok.io:17472/devtools/browser/c71c1a9d-f07c-4dd9-84a9-53a4c6df9969

И да, мой исходный код на сервере (A) получил доступ к окну браузера на сервере (B) и начал управление окном браузера. НО Я не очень понимаю как все это запустить в многопотоке т.к для управления несколькими окнами у меня будет несколько портов, под каждый порт открывать новое подключение в ngrok вряд-ли вариант. Если работать через него то нужно максимум одно соединение и потом каким-то образом перенаправлять запрос с ws://4.tcp.ngrok.io:17472 на локальный.

Я пока не понимаю как это реализовать в многопотоке, и задача усложняется тем, что за хостами (BCD) заказчик который вообще не бум бум в этих ваших интернетах, хочет нажать и чтоб все работало.

Спасибо большое!

Comment: А какую задачу вы вообще решаете? Может, задачу можно решить другим способом и удалённый доступ к браузеру на самом деле и не нужен?

Comment: Автоматизация рутинных задач в браузере, если совсем коротко, и без браузера эти задачи к сожалению никак не выполнить.

Comment: Исходный код который это все выполняет нет желания раскидывать на хосты клиентов. Сами понимаете.

Comment: Ну, лично я, если бы характер задач позволял, выполнял бы их в браузере на сервере полностью локально, а удалённым клиентам отправлял бы только результат их выполнения без какого-либо прямого доступа к браузеру